# Как получить user_id кликнувшего по inline кнопке?(aiogram)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

мне необходимо получать user_id всех кто кликает по inline кнопке. есть такой маленький код

```
@bots.callback_query_handler(text='imnobot')
async def nobot(call):
```

Что можно сделать?

Comment: а содержимое `call` смотрели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bots.callback_query_handler(text='imnobot')
async def nobot(call):
    print(call.from_user.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Команды call.message.chat.id и call.from_user.id]

На скрине цифры в  USER_ID вернулись по команде call.from_user.id
А цифры в CHAT_ID вернулись по команде call.message.chat.id

И они одинаковые

```
@bots.callback_query_handler(text='imnobot')
async def nobot(call):
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bots.callback_query_handler(text='imnobot')
async def nobot(call):
    print(call.message.chat.id)
```